# R function to take a date and output the day of the week for that date?

Tags: r

```
date_to_day_of_week_function("5/20/2020")
```

The above should output "Wednesday", an Abbreviation would be fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `format` function:

```
format(as.Date("5/20/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'), "%a")
#[1] "Wed"

format(as.Date("5/20/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'), "%A")
[1] "Wednesday"
```

All the formats can be seen in the help page of `strptime`.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to date and then use `weekdays`.

```
weekdays(as.Date("5/20/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'))
#[1] "Wednesday"
```

You can also use `lubridate` and `anytime` package to convert string to date.

```
weekdays(lubridate::mdy("5/20/2020"))
weekdays(anytime::anydate("5/20/2020"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `format` with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy("5/20/2020"), "%A")
#[1] "Wednesday"
```